# Which release of Apache POI runs with Java 1.6?

Tags: java, apache-poi

How can I find out which release of Apache POI runs with Java 1.6? I need to write ppt files with it so the poi-ooxml jar file should be capable of running with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to this [link](https://poi.apache.org/howtobuild.html) poi 3.11 needs JDK 1.6 or higher. Latest release of poi is 3.15 which is a minor release and should be compatible with JDK 1.6

Answer (score 3):

*Note: Above links are not working. Please use the following link*

Based on Apache POI [Apache Poi How to Build](http://poi.apache.org/devel/)

> JDK Version POI 4.0 and later require JDK version 1.8 or later.
>
> POI 3.11 and later 3.x versions require JDK version 1.6 or later.
>
> POI 3.5 to 3.10 required the JDK version 1.5 or later. Versions prior
>   to 3.5 required JDK 1.4+.

Answer (score 2):

As of Apache POI 3.15 (released September 2016), all of them!

As [explained here on the Apache POI site](http://poi.apache.org/howtobuild.html), all versions from POI 3.11 onwards have needed Java 6.

It's possible that in 2017, there'll be a release needing Java 7, as 7 has features that would be nice to use. However, while there's a large number of users still stuck on 6, and no killer feature needing an upgrade, there won't be a push to drop Java 6 just yet.

Comment: I'd say dropping tool support is an excellent way to get people to finally stop using Java releases that have been out of support for years (4.5 years for Java 6 except for corporations with a long term support contract). The only thing that got my previous employer to upgrade away from Windows XP was them needing an MS Office version that wouldn't run on XP...

Comment: @jwenting It's also a good way to annoy your community, to drive away new contributors, and to increase the maintenance burden as those stuck on old releases are forced to backport fixes. I think it's been less than 3 months since the last person asked on-list about Java 1.4 support!

Comment: Sure. And most of those are schoolkids who're using 10 year old textbooks and only downloaded a 1.4 JDK because that's what the book was based on at the time it was written. Tell them to use a current JDK and they will. If they insist on using old JDKs, let them use old libraries as well. I'm not complaining that I can't run 64 bit software on an old laptop that only supports 32 bit operating systems, I don't demand everyone stick to 8 bit executables because in some distant past those were the only ones you could run on your machines...

Answer (score 0):

Currently, th version available for Java 6/7 is POI 3.17 (released 09/13/2017). POI 4.0 and later need Java 8 or higher. The last version (as for 02/03/2022) is 5.2.0 (released 01/14/2022).